# Prestashop 1.7: I don't find my news texts in Themes translations

Tags: themes, translation, prestashop-1.7

I have a translation problem on my theme! I added texts in the views of my theme but I don’t find these texts (labels) in the translation parts of backoffice (localization > translations  > Themes translations > classic).

Example: 
{l s="My new text" d="Shop.Theme"} 
(themes / classic / templates / _partials / header.tpl)

Has someone already had this problem!? 
Thank you for your help!!

Nb: my theme is the default theme of prestashop (classic)
Nb: prestashop version 1.7

Answer (score 1):

I think there is something about using the classic theme. As explained here :

http://build.prestashop.com/howtos/translation/how-to-translate-your-theme

> These methods only work if you are working on a theme with a name that is not “classic”. If you’re tweaking the Classic theme and you’ve kept the “/classic” folder, your new strings won’t be detected. PrestaShop is only looking for new strings in theme folders other than “/classic”.

Answer (score 0):

I've added the same code in the same file and it's working fine to me. I found it by using the searcher.

[image]

Another option that you can try is to add a thrid level to the domain of the translation, like:

```
{l s="My new text" d="Shop.Theme.Header"}
```

And now you should see it in the expandable menu:

[image]

If you don't see now with this, be sure that you are translating the correct theme, or the Smarty template's compilation is activated in: Advanced parameters -> Performance.

Hope it helps you.